# How to import a C# plugin?

Tags: c#

How would you import a c# plugin?  Something like https://github.com/HubertJ/QuandlCS

Maybe Plugin isn't the right term but basically I would like to use this code in my Visual C# project.  How would I do that?

Comment: are you asking how to import a dll ?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any dll's in the project.  Would I need to make some for this code in order to use it?

Comment: Are there any classes?

Comment: Yes there are many.  It seems to be just a regular c# project that contains many classes.

Comment: @meda I want the QuandlCS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the source code by clicking "Download Zip" on GitHub. You then need to extract the folder and open the "QuandlCS" solution. Build the solution by clicking `Build > Build Solution` in Visual Studio.

You can then find the output `.dll` in the `QuandlCS\bin\Debug` or `Release` folder.

You can then add the library to your own project by right clicking it in Visual Studio, then clicking `Add` from the context menu, then `Reference`, and navigating to the .dll.

You could also add the entire QuandlCS project to your solution, but normally you only add the library's dll and edit it as needed.

Comment: The most detailed answer. Thanks @meda

Comment: Your right @blakepeterman +1 better answer!

Answer (score 2):

Create a project;

Right click on the solution in the Solution Explorer; Click on "Manage NuGet Packages... "

Search for QuandlCS and install. Only downside is it seems this is a fork, not the original.

[image: Nuget]

Answer (score 1):

Build the project

```
1>------ Build started: Project: QuandlCS, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  QuandlCS -> C:\Users\meda\Desktop\QuandlCS-master\QuandlCS\bin\Debug\QuandlCS.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and import the DLL `QuandlCS.dll`

Voila !

Answer (score 1):

First you would create your C# solution. Then add the QuandlCS project to it.

From there you can reference the two projects. It differs depending on your Visual Studio version but typically, you would right-click on the project then do Add -> Reference.